# How do I check if a string is composed up of characters other than my given characters in Python?

Tags: python, regex, loops, string-matching, substitution

I have a Phone numbers column in my dataframe which consists of a lot of noise. So I want to check if there is any row that is made up of any characters other than +,backslash constants and 0-9.

If it does I want to extract only those rows for all  others I want those characters to be substituted with ''. How can I do this? I am posting a minimal version of my problem as my dataset is too large.

Here is what I have tried

```
ph = ['00 9108214702Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â¢Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x80Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â¬', '080 26600704\r\n+91 9342593424']
for x in ph:
    print(re.match('^[\+0-9\r\n]+$', x))
```

which gives me none

where +0-9\r\n are permissible character. So all I want is those characters that does not match +,\r,\n,0-9 and space.

I have tried all possible suggestion to this question and none of them worked for me.

Comment: Your second string isn't matching because it contains a space, which is not matched by your regex. I'm not really sure if that's what you're asking about, as your question is very unclear. (You probably also should be using a raw string for your regex, though it doesn't seem to be causing an issue this time.)

Comment: does it have to be a regex solution?

Comment: No not necessary Liam!!! but its preferable

Comment: `What` `is` `your` `expected` `output?` It is always far more difficult to solve these things correctly when all someone can go on is a description. Seriously, `What` `is` `your` `expected` `output?`

Comment: So I want all the characters that does not match [\+0-9\r\n\s]

Comment: You need this `[^\+0-9\r\n\s]+` The `^` inside the square bracket means "ignore".

Comment: For mine use `re.findall` as opposed to match. It's more intuitive. Ket me know if you get what you need from `re.findall`

Comment: You are right! I tried and it worked if you can post an answer to this question. I would happily accept it for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> regex solution:

```
import re

ph = ['00 9108214702Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â¢Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x80Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â¬', '080 26600704\r\n+91 9342593424']

numbers = [re.findall('[\+0-9\r\n\s]+', x)[0] for x in ph]
```

> non regex solution:

```
ph = ['00 9108214702Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â¢Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x80Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â¬', '080 26600704\r\n+91 9342593424']

numbers = ["".join([c for c in x if c in "0123456789\n\r+"]) for x in ph]
```

Answer (score 1):

Non regexp solution, using sets. You can try which solution is faster. I'd imagine for long strings the regexp is the best.

```
allowed=set('abcde')

if set(ph) - allowed:
    print('String contains not allowed characters')
```